# Video style where multiple videos play as one video

Tags: video-editor, webvideos

There are a few videos I've seen where the same person, or multiple people, record their portion of the video and all videos get played back simultaneously often times in some grid usually 3x3. Most videos label themselves "medleys" and example is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyo7jzaCUhk)

**QUESTION**: Is there a proper name for this type of video? Is there an easy macbook tool to use to create this type of video?

I'd do more research on it but I can't figure out what it's called in order to do that research

Answer (score 1):

Try video montage or collage grids